# How do I show loading UI for a client component when new data is being fetched in server component in Nextjs 13 app router

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js13, app-router

I am fetching data in server component and passing that data to client component, Initially I have a loading.jsx file which wraps the page.js file and any children in a  boundary. Now the problem is when the user interacts with the client component and searches for a new location it fetches new data but no loading ui is shown and new data just automatically gets shown in the client component(btw I use searchParams in Page.js as global state to fetch new data for that location). I would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Here is my code...
#/page.js

```
export default async function Overview({ searchParams }) {
const cityPollutionData = await getChartsData(cityParam);

return (
    <div>
      <TopFiveCard
        topFiveData={topFiveData}
        pollutant={pollutant}
        // mapGeoJsonData={geoJsonFeatures}
      />
        <CityPollutionCard
          cityPollutionData={cityPollutionData}
        />
      <LearnMoreCard />
    </div>
  );
```

#/CityPollutionCard.jsx

```
"use client"
const CityPollutionCard = ({cityPollutionData}) => {
  let searchParams = useSearchParams();
  let pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();
const getCityData = async (cityName) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
    params.set("city", cityName[0].toUpperCase() + cityName.slice(1));
    const url = `${pathname}?${params}`;
    router.push(url, { scroll: false });
  };
return (
<CitySearchBar getCityData={getCityData} />
<ApexChart
   seriesData={seriesData}
   pollutantName={pollutant}
   colorStops={cityPollutionData.colorStops}
 />
)}
```

p.s. I had to make the cityPollutionCard client component because I needed to use hooks and add interactive js